# Display GeoJSON data depending on the selected value from select option in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I am making a map in Leaflet then I made a custom route using LineString in GeoJSON. I have this navigate modal where users can select the Starting Area and the Destination Area. Here is how I implemented it:

```
<label for="startingArea">Starting Area</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="startingArea" required>
        <option selected hidden value="">Select Starting Area</option>
        <option value="Building A">Building A</option>
        <option value="Building B">Building B</option>
        <option value="Building C">Building C</option>
        <option value="Building D">Building D</option>
    </select>
 </div>

<label for="destinationArea">Destination</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="destinationArea" required>
        <option selected hidden value="">Select Starting Area</option>
        <option value="Building A">Building A</option>
        <option value="Building B">Building B</option>
        <option value="Building C">Building C</option>
        <option value="Building D">Building D</option>
     </select>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="clearReportTextArea();">Cancel</button>
    <button id="start-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Start</button>
</div>
```

Now I want that, if user select Starting Area as Building A and Destination Area as Building B, I want to display the specific route that I have made for Building A and B. Here's the script:

```
// route style
var building_route = L.geoJson(null, {
    style: function (feature) {
        return {
            color: "green",
            fill: false,
            opacity: 1,
            weight: 5,
        };
    },
});

var start = document.getElementById("startingArea");
var finish = document.getElementById("destinationArea").value;

if (start == "Building A" && finish == "Building B") {
  $.getJSON("data/ba-to-bb-route.geojson", function (data) {
    building_route.addData(data);
  });
}

$("#start-btn").click(function () {
  building_route.addTo(map);
  return false;
});
```

The code obviously doesn't work, what's the problem here?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you know where it fails? Please include any error messages as formatted text in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you are getting start and destination values and getting GeoJSON data before start and destination is being selected and then processed within `click` processing function. There's also `value` property missing when getting start point value.

You have to put all data processing inside `click` processing function. Code could then look something like this:

```
$("#start-btn").click(function () {
  var start = document.getElementById("startingArea").value;
  var finish = document.getElementById("destinationArea").value;

  if (start == "Building A" && finish == "Building B") {
    $.getJSON("data/ba-to-bb-route.geojson", function (data) {
      if (map.hasLayer(building_route))
        building_route.clearLayers();
      else {
        building_route.addTo(map);
      }
      building_route.addData(data);
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```